# jquery accordion get height value

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-ui-accordion

I'd like to get the height value of the individual panels when active. I know I can use `$(document).height()` or `$(window).height()`, but I want to actual height value of the active panel. Is this possible?

```
<ul id="allTabs">                           
  <li><a id="tab-1" href="#buildTab" onclick='windowResize("mainAccordion");' >Build</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab-5" href="#setupTab" onclick='windowResize("setupAccordion");'>Setup</a></li>
</ul>

function windowResize(what){
  var setupActive=$('#mainSetupAccordion').accordion('option', 'active').toString();
  var mainActive=$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active').toString();

  if (what=='setupAccordion'){
    var windowHeight=$('#mainSetupAccordion').outerHeight(true);
    var buttons=0;
  };

  if (what=='mainAccordion'){var windowHeight=$('#accordion').outerHeight(true); var buttons=25};
  if (setupActive=='false' && what=='setupAccordion'){windowHeight=104};
  if (mainActive=='false' && what=='mainAccordion'){windowHeight=79};      

  var window_size=windowHeight+87+buttons;

  $('#tab_sizes').val(window_size);
  window.location='skp:resizeWindow';
};
```

Basically I'm trying to get the window to dynamically resize along with the accordion, which works if I stay within the tab. If I switch tabs the result I get is 0 not the accordion panel value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$('#activePanel').outerHeight(true);
```

if you have multiple accordions give all the same class and use .each();

```
$('.Panels').each(function(){
     var actualHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
     console.log(actualHeight );
});
```

Comment: That works great, but is there a way to make this generic for multiple accordions?

Comment: @FrankN updated answer .. may be you need to use if statement if you looking for just visible divs or a specific class for active accordion .. may be .. Good Luck

Comment: I just realised the problem I'm having doesn't have anything to do with multiple accordions. My accordions are in tabs and when I switch back between tabs the outerHeight is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work, revised function... it might not be pretty but it works.

```
function windowResize(what){
  var setupActive=$('#mainSetupAccordion').accordion('option', 'active').toString();
  var mainActive=$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active').toString();

  if (what=='setupAccordion'){
    var windowHeight=$('#mainSetupAccordion').outerHeight(true);
    var buttons=0;
    if (setupActive=='false' && what=='setupAccordion'){windowHeight=104};
    if (windowHeight!=0) {
        setupAccordionPanel=[]
        setupAccordionPanel.push(windowHeight)
    }else{
        windowHeight=setupAccordionPanel[0]
    }
  };

  if (what=='mainAccordion'){
    var windowHeight=$('#accordion').outerHeight(true);
    var buttons=25
    if (mainActive=='false' && what=='mainAccordion'){windowHeight=79};      
    if (windowHeight!=0) {
        mainAccordionPanel=[]
        mainAccordionPanel.push(windowHeight)
    }else{
        windowHeight=mainAccordionPanel[0]
    }
  };

  var window_size=windowHeight+87+buttons;
  $('#tab_sizes').val(window_size);
  window.location='skp:resizeWindow';
};
```